# How to web scrape a site which has the same url for multiple page jumps?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup and I want to scrape the data(transfer fees and players names) from this site -  www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2000

But you'll notice that the page only displays first 25 names. You have to click 'next' to view the next 25 names and so on and on for ten pages. However, the URL doesn't change. 
I'm using this code by fcpython.com -

>

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2000"
page1 = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2018&land_id=157&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&w_s=s"
page2 = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2018&land_id=157&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&w_s=s"

pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})

#My Code for printing all 25 names and fees

#for i in range(0, 25):
    #print(Players[i].text, Values[i].text)

PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []

for i in range(0,25):
    PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
    ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList})

print(df.head(25))
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to get all the results at one go? Or get them at all(since I can't go past 25)?

Comment: Open the development console in your browser by pressing F12, switch to the network tab, filter out images in the network list and navigate in the website. You will then see what urls the site uses internally to retrieve the data

Comment: I have tried my best for you let me know if it works.

Comment: It will return all 250 values as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the following code to achieve your goal.You have to use `webdriver` to click the next button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2000")
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []

for loop in range(0,10):
  Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
  Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
  for pl, val in zip(Players, Values):

    PlayersList.append(pl.text)
    ValuesList.append(val.text)
  if loop==9:
      break
  else:
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.naechste-seite").click()


df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList})

print(df.head(250))
```

Output:

```
                     Players   Values
0                  Luís Figo  £54.00m
1              Hernán Crespo  £51.13m
2              Marc Overmars  £36.00m
3          Gabriel Batistuta  £32.54m
4             Nicolas Anelka  £31.05m
5              Rio Ferdinand  £23.40m
6           Flávio Conceicao  £22.50m
7             Savo Milosevic  £22.50m
8            David Trézéguet  £20.92m
9              Claudio López  £20.70m
10   Jimmy Floyd Hasselbaink  £20.25m
11              Gerard López  £19.44m
12                     Lucas  £19.17m
13               Pablo Aimar  £19.13m
14             Wálter Samuel  £18.72m
15             Shabani Nonda  £18.00m
16              Robbie Keane  £17.55m
17                 José Mari  £17.10m
18           Jonathan Zebina  £16.56m
19                   Émerson  £16.20m
20            Tore André Flo  £16.20m
21             Serhii Rebrov  £16.20m
22            Angelo Peruzzi  £16.11m
23             Diego Tristán  £15.98m
24           Sylvain Wiltord  £15.75m
25                 Luís Figo  £54.00m
26             Hernán Crespo  £51.13m
27             Marc Overmars  £36.00m
28         Gabriel Batistuta  £32.54m
29            Nicolas Anelka  £31.05m
..                       ...      ...
220           Tore André Flo  £16.20m
221            Serhii Rebrov  £16.20m
222           Angelo Peruzzi  £16.11m
223            Diego Tristán  £15.98m
224          Sylvain Wiltord  £15.75m
225                Luís Figo  £54.00m
226            Hernán Crespo  £51.13m
227            Marc Overmars  £36.00m
228        Gabriel Batistuta  £32.54m
229           Nicolas Anelka  £31.05m
230            Rio Ferdinand  £23.40m
231         Flávio Conceicao  £22.50m
232           Savo Milosevic  £22.50m
233          David Trézéguet  £20.92m
234            Claudio López  £20.70m
235  Jimmy Floyd Hasselbaink  £20.25m
236             Gerard López  £19.44m
237                    Lucas  £19.17m
238              Pablo Aimar  £19.13m
239            Wálter Samuel  £18.72m
240            Shabani Nonda  £18.00m
241             Robbie Keane  £17.55m
242                José Mari  £17.10m
243          Jonathan Zebina  £16.56m
244                  Émerson  £16.20m
245           Tore André Flo  £16.20m
246            Serhii Rebrov  £16.20m
247           Angelo Peruzzi  £16.11m
248            Diego Tristán  £15.98m
249          Sylvain Wiltord  £15.75m
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kajal Kundu! I haven't ever worked with Selenium but really your help was appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requests.session` and use the ajax request done by website which you can find using your browser as suggested by @NineBerry in the comments.

This will add all the players and values to the list:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/plus/0/galerie/0?saison_id=2000"
PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []
page_num = 2
session = requests.Session()
while True:
    pageTree = session.get(page, headers=headers)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
    Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
    Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
    for player, value in zip(Players, Values):
        PlayersList.append(player.text)
        ValuesList.append(value.text)
    if pageSoup.find("li", {"title": "Go to next page"}):
        page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/ajax/yw2/saison_id/2000/plus/0/galerie/0/page/{}?ajax=yw2".format(page_num)
        page_num +=1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: @Abhishek, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.